# Почему не работает код пирамидальной сортировки (сортировки кучей)

Tags: java, сортировка

Я не понимаю почему мой код сортировки не работает, но вроде бы все правильно сделано по теории. Например, для входных данных 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, вывод бывает 1, 2, 5, 3, 4.

```
public class Main {
  
  public static void heapSort(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = n / 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      heapify(a, n, i);
    }
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      swap(a, i, 0);
      heapify(a, i, 0);
    }
  }
  
  public static void heapify(int[] heap, int n, int i) {
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    int largest = i;
    if (l < n && heap[l] > heap[i]) {
      largest = l;
    }
    if (r < n && heap[r] > heap[i]) {
      largest = r;
    }
    if (i != largest) {
      swap(heap, i, largest);
      heapify(heap, n, largest);
    }
  }
  
  public static int right(int i) {
    return 2 * i + 2;
  }
  
  public static int left(int i) {
    return 2 * i + 1;
  }
  
  public static void swap(int[] heap, int i1, int i2) {
    int temp = heap[i1];
    heap[i1] = heap[i2];
    heap[i2] = temp;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = new int[] {2, 3, 1, 5, 4};
    heapSort(A);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
      System.out.println(A[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в методе heapify, в условиях. 
Так выглядит правильный метод:

```
  public static void heapify(int[] heap, int n, int i) {
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    int largest = i;
    if (l < n && heap[l] > heap[largest]) {
      largest = l;
    }
    if (r < n && heap[r] > heap[largest]) {
      largest = r;
    }
    if (i != largest) {
      swap(heap, i, largest);
      heapify(heap, n, largest);
    }
  }
```